# Memory error in Python while using fractions

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

I am using the stern-brocot sequence to generate fractions. These fractions have been appended to list. Now I need to modify this list of fractions as the problem requires me to satisfy 2 conditions on the fractions that exist in the list.

1) for every simplified fraction `a/b` that is present in the list, `b/2a` must also be present.

2) for every 2 simplified fractions `a/b` and `c/d`, `(a+b)/(c+d)`
 should also be present.

I've written to following code to just do that.

```
# Python program to print 
# Brocot Sequence
from fractions import Fraction

import math

class MyFraction:  # This class has been defined to return unsimplified fractions as they are as the'd get simplified using the fractions module
    def __init__(self, numerator=1, denominator=1):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    def get_fraction(self):
        return Fraction(numerator=self.numerator, denominator=self.denominator)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.numerator, self.denominator)


def SternSequenceFunc(BrocotSequence, n):

    # loop to create sequence
    for i in range(1, n):

        considered_element = BrocotSequence[i]
        precedent = BrocotSequence[i-1]

        # adding sum of considered
        # element and it's precedent
        BrocotSequence.append(considered_element + precedent)

        # adding next considered element
        BrocotSequence.append(considered_element)


    # printing sequence..
     for i in range(0, n):
        print(BrocotSequence[i] , end=" ")

     print("\n")

# Function to determine if a fraction is simplified or not

def is_simplified(frac):

    if frac == Fraction(frac.numerator, frac.denominator):

        return True

    else:

        return False

# Function to modify the set to satisfy the given conditions

def modify_set(list_fractions):

    # To satisfy the 1st condition
    for fraction in list_fractions:
        numerator = fraction.numerator
        denominator = fraction.denominator
        list_fractions.append(MyFraction(denominator, 2*numerator))

    # To satisfy the 2nd condition
    for fraction in list_fractions:
        if is_simplified(fraction):
            for frac in list_fractions:
                if frac != fraction:
                    if is_simplified(frac):
                        f = MyFraction((fraction.numerator+frac.numerator), (fraction.denominator+frac.denominator))
                        list_S.append(f)

while True: 

    list_S = []

    count = 0
    # Driver code
    n = int(input("Enter value of n : "))
    BrocotSequence = []

    # adding first two element
    # in the sequence
    BrocotSequence.append(1)
    BrocotSequence.append(1)

    SternSequenceFunc(BrocotSequence, n)

    for i in range(1, n):
        list_S.append(Fraction(BrocotSequence[i], BrocotSequence[i-1])) # Appending the list with fractions generated from stern-brocot sequence

    modify_set(list_S)

    print("\n Printing all fractions : \n")
    for fraction in list_S:
        count = count + 1
        print("\n", fraction)

    print("Number of fractions: {}".format(count))
```

After running this code, I got a `Memory Error` while running the `modify_set` function. I don't understand why. Can anyone help me understand why and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you ever `break` the `while True` loop?

Comment: The Stern-Brocot tree is infinite. Are you trying to do an infinite amount of computation?

Comment: You get an error while *compiling*? Or while *running* the function?

Comment: I am accepting a integer value from the user and there will be that many iterations in the sequence. So, it is not infinite in my case.

Comment: @FreeRadical: What value do you pass?

Comment: JacoblRR, I do not. I made it an infinite while loop to continuously accept input from the user. How does that matter by the way?

Comment: 10 @ShadowRanger

Comment: @Barmer, while `running`. My apologies, I made the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding to a `list` as you iterate it here:

```
for fraction in list_fractions:
    numerator = fraction.numerator
    denominator = fraction.denominator
    list_fractions.append(MyFraction(denominator, 2*numerator))
```

Each time you pull one element from `list_fractions`, then add a new one (which will eventually be iterated in turn). So this loop never ends, and the `list` grows forever (or until the `MemoryError` anyway).

Similarly, in your next loop in that function (not that you'd ever reach it), you've got a nested loop over `list_fractions`, and while it's less obvious here, it would also be infinite, because each iteration appends to `list_S` (which is a global), which was passed as the `list_fractions` argument, so they're both aliases to the same `list` (Python function calls don't copy the contents of their arguments, only the reference itself, so anything aside from rebinding `list_fractions` to a new object would modify `list_S` too).

I don't know your intended logic, but if the goal is to only add new entries for the existing entries (and not process the added entries), a solution would be to iterate over a shallow copy of the `list`, e.g.:

```
# list_fractions[:] returns a new list with references to the same values as
# the original list, but unaffected by subsequent additions and removals
for fraction in list_fractions[:]:
    numerator = fraction.numerator
    denominator = fraction.denominator
    list_fractions.append(MyFraction(denominator, 2*numerator))
```

Your nested loop will be more complicated (depending on whether the inner loop should process an updated copy of `list_fractions` or not); I'll leave you to determine the correct course of action.

Comment: Got it, Thanks @ShadowRanger.